# Can I inject a thread in a remote app domain from C#

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, code-injection

I was wondering if its possible to inject a thread into a remote app domain running in a separate process.

My guess is that I could do this using the debugging interfaces (ICorDebug) but I was wondering if there is any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done there is sample code in [snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/) It sets up a hook, and using managed c++ tells the appdomain to load an assembly. Really impressive ...

Answer (score 1):

There was recently an announcement of a new facility Mono provides to do just this.  See this post on [assembly injection](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Sep-29.html).

Answer (score 0):

Mike Stall has an [interesting sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2006/09/28/managed-create-remote-thread.aspx) on how to use CreateRemoteThread to inject remote threads in managed apps.

This answer is still incomplete, cause I would like to run new code in the remote appdomain. I guess I could try creating 1 new thread that loads a library for me, and another that will call a place in my new library to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

There's another way by using `SetThreadContext`, and by changing the EIP of the target process.
However I don't know how you would do that in C#.